# meta_query displays all results and none, my query is wrong

Tags: meta-query

I´ve read almost this articles but unfortunately my query is no working, I think i´m very close but could be so far away.

I´m trying to get metadata using a custom form with method get,

```
$rob = $_GET['rob'];  
$bedrooms = $_GET['beds'];  
$bathrooms = $_GET['baths'];
```

the array is:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'beds_value',
            'value' => '$bedrooms',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'baths_value',
            'value' => '$bathrooms',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'rob_value',
            'value' => '$rob',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),          
    ),
);
    
$args = array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query );
query_posts( $args );
```

depending on final query the results are diferent

this display none, seems to be this clean the query

```
$args = array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query );
query_posts( $args );
```

but if is used `$query = new WP_Query( $args );` I get all results without any filter.
but I can see the query data Ex 2 beds, 2 baths

Do I need to write something more?

Comment: you don't need to put quotes round variables when passing them into the query

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are using single quotes in passing values to query (e.g. `'value' => '$bedrooms'`), but this way the variables are not expanded (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Simply use `'value' => $bedrooms`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used the valiable without quotes and the results has changed from no results to All results. Now I changed the code 'relation' => 'OR', to 'relation' => 'AND' 
Now I get filtered some data, but no relations about data query, I mean if selected 2 beds and 2 baths I get information about 2 and 3 beds, and also 1 and 2 baths

Comment: I think you may omit the `'relation' => 'AND'`, it's implicit. Moreover if you don't need string pattern matching you may omit the `'compare' => 'LIKE'` too and it will uses `'compare' => '='` as default. Please post your actual code to get more help.

Comment: <pre><code>    
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
 'relation' => 'OR',

            array(
            'key' => 'beds_value',
            'value' => $bedrooms,
            'compare' => '=',
            
         ),
   array(
            'key' => 'baths_value',
            'value' => $bathrooms,
            'compare' => '=',
            
   ),
   array(
            'key' => 'rob_value',
            'value' => $rob,
            'compare' => '=',
            
         ),         
    ),
 );
 
 $args = array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query );
 query_posts( $args );
<code>

Comment: Changing the relation 'relation' => 'OR' to 'relation' => 'AND' I got no results and omiting the line 'relation' => 'OR' also I got no results.

So now is querying but only one meta_data but I would like to have querys for 2 or three options... Sorry for distorted code, I can`t put the gray block

Comment: The problem may be in the way you made the `array_merge`. I think you should change the order of parameters: `array_merge( $wp_query->query , $args );`

Comment: Changing the order it doesn´t affect the result<code>$args = array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query );
 query_posts( $args );  </code> to <code>
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query , $args );  
 query_posts( $args ); </code> what else could be affecting my query? I think that could be something related with 'relation'=>'X' because 'OR' extract data from one $value and the option 'AND' can´t extract accurate values cause it gets confused and do nothing.

Comment: Omiting the line $args = array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query ); doesnt affect the query the line query_posts( $args );  is enough to display results

Comment: Further advice: double check the naming of your variables and array indexes. It's easy to make confusion when there is not uniformity (i.e. you use bathrooms baths and baths_value for the same piece of information in different context). Using always the same name for the same information would help. 
You may also give a look to the SQL query that is built (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Class_Variables)

Comment: Ok, bath is the name of input field from search form; using GET this name is converted as string value like $bathrooms to feed the array as value, the baths_values is the name of the field on the database to compare and extract by query.

I started to do this because the web page was using wpdb query but owner never got the query paged (more than 300 producst on same page), I tried to change to meta-query so now I get paged all query but only for one option. I'm thinking to ask for a wpdb query with this options to get paged the query, if is a better option.